# How will iterate over a slice if that slice increases inside the loop?

Tags: go, slice

When I iterate through the for loop on the slide (code below), I get the output Output: `0A,1M,2C,`

code:

```
x := []string{"A", "B", "C"}

for i, s := range x {
    print(i, s, ",")
    x[i+1] = "M"
    x = append(x, "Z")
    x[i+1] = "Z"
}
```

Why is the output exactly like that and **not** `0A, 1Z, 2Z`?

Reading the documentation, I saw that the slice is passed to the function by a pointer to the array it is based on.

Is the slice also passed to the for loop by pointer? (couldn't find why in the documentation)

If so, my guess as to why the output is exactly 0A, 1M, 2C, - because, originally, the slice was passed to the loop by pointer, and when the capacity of the slice is doubled in the first iteration of the loop, the print(i, s) values are still printed based on the base array. Is this true?

Comment: everything in go is passed by value, the slice in the for expression is no exception. You are writing to a different backing array, because like you said, a new array is allocated for `append`

Comment: You can easily play with the example to see what's going on by setting the initial capacity: https://go.dev/play/p/24fiDYh_YFa

Comment: @JimB does this mean that the slice is passed to the for loop by value, but is actually passed a copy of the pointer to the structure, which contains a pointer to the array of elements, the length of the slice, and its capacity?

Comment: "by value" means it must be a copy, but there is no pointer to the structure, just the structure itself.

Comment: @JimB I understand that in the loop `for i, s := range x` i and s are copies, but what's bugging me is that based on my comment above, the slice is essentially a pointer. When we write `range x` - this x means a copy of our slice, which is essentially a copy of the pointer?

Comment: No, a slice is not "essentially a pointer" (and thinking of it as such will lead to the type of confusion you are showing here), a slice is clearly a struct containing a pointer to an array, a length and a capacity. Maybe https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro will clear things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`append` can allocate a new array. It does. After the first `append`, `x` is now a copy and you're looping over the original. Changes to `x` now have no affect on `s`.

Let's mark up the loop with some more debugging to see.

```
x := []string{"A", "B", "C"}

for i, s := range x {
    fmt.Printf("Start: i=%v s=%v x=%p %v\n", i, s, x, x)
    x[i+1] = "M"
    fmt.Printf("After x[i+1] = \"M\": i=%v s=%v x=%p %v\n", i, s, x, x)
    x = append(x, "Z")
    fmt.Printf("After Append: i=%v s=%v x=%p %v\n", i, s, x, x)
    x[i+1] = "Z"
    fmt.Printf("After x[i+1] = \"Z\": i=%v s=%v x=%p %v\n\n", i, s, x, x)
}
```

[And the result](https://play.golang.com/p/5c1RNuOXzAH)...

```
Start: i=0 s=A x=0xc0000161b0 [A B C]
After x[i+1] = "M": i=0 s=A x=0xc0000161b0 [A M C]
After Append: i=0 s=A x=0xc000062180 [A M C Z]
After x[i+1] = "Z": i=0 s=A x=0xc000062180 [A Z C Z]

Start: i=1 s=M x=0xc000062180 [A Z C Z]
After x[i+1] = "M": i=1 s=M x=0xc000062180 [A Z M Z]
After Append: i=1 s=M x=0xc000062180 [A Z M Z Z]
After x[i+1] = "Z": i=1 s=M x=0xc000062180 [A Z Z Z Z]

Start: i=2 s=C x=0xc000062180 [A Z Z Z Z]
After x[i+1] = "M": i=2 s=C x=0xc000062180 [A Z Z M Z]
After Append: i=2 s=C x=0xc000062180 [A Z Z M Z Z]
After x[i+1] = "Z": i=2 s=C x=0xc000062180 [A Z Z Z Z Z]
```

Note how after the first `append` the address of `x` changes. Any `x[i+`] = ?`no longer affect`s`.